# What is the meaning of this linker warning and how I can fix it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

I am getting this warning during li king my application which uses several library,

```
warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ??1?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UEAA@XZ (public: virtual __cdecl std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)) imported
```

What it means and how I can solve it?

Comment: Have you tried searching the internet?  Here's what I found: [LNK4049](https://www.google.com/search?q=lnk4049&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes, I looked at them but could not understand what they means and how I can fix it, so the question here :)

Comment: You normally get a lot more warnings about this mishap, it is a pretty serious one that you cannot ignore.  One of the libraries was built with incompatible compiler options, ought to be /MT vs /MD.  High odds for having very hard to diagnose runtime errors.  Use the linker's /VERBOSE option to see where this function came from.

Answer (score 1):

What it means is you have a symbol that is defined with  __declspec(dllexport) and  __declspec(dllimport) in the same DLL.  In other words you have told the linker:

This symbol is defined in this DLL, and 
   This symbol is not defined in this DLL.

Since the symbol is basic_ios it is a symbol in the C++ runtime library.  What you have probably done is specify in one place that the run time library is statically linked, but in a different place you have specified that the run time library is dynamically linked.

Check the properties in visual studio and make sure they are consistent.